# Price Elasticiyt of Demand & (AR - MR)

Tags: mathematical-economics, elasticity, producer-theory

I have the following question:

> Using this equation: $MR = P(1+\frac{1}{ε})$ and the attached graph. How does the vertical distance between the demand curve and MR curve at a given level of output depend on the PeD (ε) at that output level.

**My Answer:**

Vertical Distance $= AR - MR = \frac{p•q}{q} - p(1+\frac{1}{ε}) = -\frac{p}{ε}$

**Book Answer:**

> The equation for ε implies that $\frac{MR}{p} = 1+\frac{1}{ε}$. Hence, the less elastic is the demand (assuming $ε < -1$), the smaller will be the ratio $\frac{MR}{p}$

**Questions:**

1. Is my answer correct?
2. How does their answer relate to the distance between MR & AR?
3. How does their answer relate to my answer?

[image]

Comment: Does your $\epsilon$ include the negative sign or is it the absolute value of the elasticity?

Comment: I'm assuming that ε is negative, i.e.$-\frac{p}{ε} \ge 0$, thanks for checking!...And as a result of your comment, i have just fixed the typo. It now reads "(assuming $ε  < -1$)"  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that since $AR = P$, the ratio $\frac{MR}{P}$ is actually $\frac{MR}{AR}$.

Notice $\frac{MR}{AR} = 1 + \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ falls from $1$ to $0$ continuously as $\epsilon$ moves from $-\infty$ to $-1$.

This is what happens in the graph from $q = 0$ to $q = q_1$.

At $q = 0$,

$\epsilon = \frac{\partial q}{\partial P} \cdot \frac{P}{q} \to - \infty $ as $q \to 0$.

At $q = q_1$, we have

$MR = 0 \implies 0 = MR = \frac{\partial Pq}{\partial q} = P + q \frac{\partial P}{\partial q} \implies \frac{\partial P}{\partial q} = - \frac{P}{q}$

By the inverse function rule,

$\frac{\partial q}{\partial P} = - \frac{q}{P} \implies \epsilon = \frac{\partial q}{\partial P} \cdot \frac{P}{q} = -1 $

It is easy to check that $\frac{MR}{AR} = 1 + \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ for $\epsilon < -1$ is increasing in $\epsilon$, or equivalently, decreasing in $|\epsilon|$.

—————————-—————————-—

Your answer is mathematically correct, I think it’s more an issue of what the book’s author intended the exercise for.

From the textbook’s answer, we can express the markup formula of monopoly power, by noting that $AR = P$ and at the profit maximizing quantity, $MR = MC$.

Therefore,

$\frac{MC}{P} = 1 + \frac{1}{\epsilon} \implies \text{Markup} = \frac{P - MC}{P} = 1 - \frac{MC}{P} = - \frac{1}{\epsilon} = \frac{1}{|\epsilon|}$

—————————-—————————-——

Your answer also shows that for $\epsilon \to - \infty$, $AR - MR \to 0$, which is what happens as $q \to 0$.

The above is equivalent to the ratio $\frac{MR}{AR} \to 1$.

Notice your answer can be rewritten as $AR - MR = \frac{P}{|\epsilon|}$ which increases continuously as $\epsilon$ gets less negative (the demand is less elastic).

From your answer we can also see that when $\epsilon = -1$, $AR - MR = P$. This happens when $MR = 0$, since we always have $AR = P$.

The above is equivalent to the ratio $\frac{MR}{AR} = 0$.

Your answer is related to the textbook’s answer. The main difference is that yours is expressed in terms of arithmetic difference, while the textbook’s is expressed in terms of ratios.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detail Nicholas, apologies you went to such great lengths and i didn't have chance to review it yet. I will do ASAP and let you know if i have any questions. Thank again!